# flutter GestureDetector ListView

Tags: flutter

When I have a `ListView` in `GestureDetector` and I override `onVerticalDragUpdate` method, the `ListView` can't scroll. 
How can I both override `onVerticalDragUpdate` method so that `ListView` remains scrollable?

```
new GestureDetector(
              onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) => print("a"),
              child: new ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text("a"),
                  new Text("a"),
                  new Text("a"),
                ],
              ),
            )
```

Comment: Basically you can't. If you tell us the usecase for this, maybe we can give an alternative.

Comment: I have a use case for this. I have a listview that I want to be movable to another section of the screen in case the user wants to see details below that ListView, but it also needs to scroll

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inspect the `DragUpdateDetails`, you can wrap the `ListView` inside of a `NotificationListener`.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NotificationListener(
        onNotification: (notification) {
          if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
            print('${notification.dragDetails}');
          }
        },
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('Index = $index'),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: it can stop scroll?

Comment: @Layou What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want a scroll bottom sheet,i got it ,https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/21896